# Verification Email Form In Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, forms, codeigniter, email

I have an edit model, contains 2 forms, name and e-mail, I put some javascript in my form, so when user edit their name/email, program will check whether the name/email already in database or not, if already in database there will be alert that show the name/email already exist.

The problem is, for name form that code is work perfectly but when I tried it in email form, it's only read one if statement which is will say error email already exist even though the email not exist in database.

One important things is that URL in `codeigniter` can't read symbols like `@`, so the same code for name verification cannot be use in email verification, so i made a new function and all my related code just like this:

**Model**

```
function email_exists($email)
{
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $query = $this->db->get('petugas');
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){ return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function register_email_exists()
{
    if (array_key_exists('email',$_POST)) {
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        if ($this->Crud->email_exists($email) == TRUE ) {
            echo false;
        } else {
            echo true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var check5; 
$("#editemail").bind("keyup change", function(){
    var editemail = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'kasir/cekEmailEdit2',
        type:"POST",
        data:{send:true, email:email},
        success:function(data){ alert(email);
            if (editemail!=oldEmail){
                if(data==true){
                    //email not exist in database, so form can be edit
                    $("#report5").text("berhasil karna nama email baru");
                    check5=1; 
                }else{
                    //email exist in database, show alert
                    $("#report5").text("*email sudah terpakai"); 
                    check5=0; 
                }
            }else{
                //success submit form because no data has been changed
                $("#report5").text("berhasil karna gajadi ganti email");
                check5=1; 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to enter email which is already in database and see result. and change your controller. use true instead of false and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function email_exists($email)
{
    return $this->db->where('email', $email)->count_all_results('petugas');
}

public function register_email_exists()
{
    $result = array(
        'status' => 1 // denotes exists
    );

    if($this->input->post('email') != ''){
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        if($this->Crud->email_exists($email)){
            $result['status'] = 1;
        }else{
            $result['status'] = 0;
        }
    }

    echo header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

The JS part:

```
success:function(data){ 
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    if(data.status){
        alert('Exists');
    }else{
        alert('Not exists');
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing happen, at first the alert `*emailexist` shows up, but after use your code, right now nothing happen no notification at all, and it is affected my name form. also what the use for `count_all_results('petugas')`

Comment: Check you console, network tab for the response you are getting. `count_all_results()` is short form of `count()` in mysql which gives mumeric output. Added one line in the JS function please follow.